# Python: Writing memory of a process

Tags: python, memory, process

So I've been having some problems with editing process memory. The way I usually do it is manual using process hacker 2, it's used for looking at all sorts of processes on your pc, and is VERY useful for finding what programs you've launched, no matter the extention.

And that is what I want to prevent. I want to hide the fact that I've ran some exe's by writing over the strings that popup when looking for them in for example: explorer.exe, -s DPS (svchost.exe), etc...).

You might need to download process hacker 2 to find out what I mean, but if you already know, please respond.

So far my attempts of making it work have been unsuccesful, and I'm starting to lose hope that it's even possible.

Comment: The solution to this depends on the scope of what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to make it so your process doesn't show up in process hacker 2 specifically.?  Or do you want to hide you process from any tool that queries the system for processes?

Comment: okay basically here's what happens; whenever and whatever exe you run, it appears in what we call DPS (Diagnostic Policy Service), and when using PH2, you're able to look up any string for any exe (the name, or dps date) and then do what you want to it. What I would do is spoof it by just typing in random characters instead of the string, and that would basically destroy most evidence of it (except for basic file cleanign in prefetch, recents etc ...).

I would like to be able to do that, but automatically, which will also make it more descrete since logs wouldn't show me opening PH2.

Comment: it wouldn't be hidden from PH2 only, since PH2 is used for vewing/editing existing memory, so whatever you edit in PH2, won't only be affected in PH2 (sorry for my bad explanation, english isn't my best language lol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use Memorpy**

```
import memorpy, psutil

cheat_name = "autoclicker.exe" #this is the string we are looking for inside svchost.exe's memory
pids = []

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == "svchost.exe":
        pids.append(proc.pid) #we loop through every process to find svchost

for pid in pids:
    mw = memorpy.MemWorker(pid=pid)
    l = [x for x in mw.mem_search(cheat_name)]
    print l
    for string in l:
        string.write(' '*len(cheat_name)*2) #here we replace the cheat's name with spaces
        print "Deleted some strings!"
```

It basically loops through every svchost.exe, searches for cheat_name and replaces it with spaces.
Note: Memorpy only supports python 2.x.
You also have to run the program as administrator.

Comment: this is exactly what I've been looking for, but is there any way at all to have it supported on py3?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to use memorpy with python 3, but there are other memory editing libraries which you should try it if you must use it with python 3.

Comment: before I do some researching on them, would you happen to know some off the top of your head? I've already tried pymem, but it can't be used for the same type of memory modding I'd like, and it's over complicated.

Comment: Well, from a quick google search, I found "mem-edit", which seems to have everything you need to clean strings from processes, and is made in python 3. It's also pretty easy to use. Btw, since I guess you want to hide cheats in a screenshare, in order to clean every process and not run into any Permission Denied errors, I recommend you use token impersonation to start the program as System.

Comment: your mind is just simply too large, thank you very much for this. I'll learn more about token impersonation. Cheers mate.